# IdentityServer4 keeps cancelling token requests after one minute

Tags: identityserver4

I am using the Skoruba Identity Server 4 Admin Template.

The 'connect/token' end point keeps getting cancelled after exactly 1.7 minutes for one of our web APIs.
The API is consumed by a windows service and a web app.

The windows service pushes data to the api every five minutes, and runs on multiple clients.

The service, web app and API uses the same IS4 application for authentication.

Is there any explanation for why the token requests get cancelled after exactly 1.7 minutes every time for only this particular API.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "cancelled" in this case? How exactly does it preset? A 401 response from an API? If so does it also include a WWW-Authenticate response header?

Comment: Yes, the API responds with 401 to the service and web app.
When looking at the IS4's insights on azure we see can see that the 'connect/token' end point runs for exactly 1.7 minutes and then get literally cancelled.
I have no way to recreate the problem locally because the problem only occurs on production.

Comment: As in calls to that endpoint are taking 1.7 minutes to execute? If so that's clearly wrong and it's likely timing out.

Comment: Yes the calls to that endpoint is taking 1.7 minutes to execute.
I am using the IS4 template application, and that endpoint is no where to be found. I'm guessing it's in one of their NuGet packages. In addition, I use the oidc-client package for the angular application, where there is no endpoint config except for callbacks to the web app itself

Comment: Please note that this problem only occurs with this particular API